# Adding multiple commands under scripts stage in Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-repos

I need to execute following commands in the project repo to a do a build

```
 echo Building Software/linux_framework
 source /opt/pkg/linux/settings.sh
 cd Software/linux_framework
 make images HARDWARE=../my_xsa/ BOARD=local
```

Snippet from my YAML file:

```
pool:
  name: Default

steps:
- script: echo Building Software/linux_framework
          source /opt/pkg/linux/settings.sh
          cd Software/linux_framework 
          make images HARDWARE=../my_xsa/ BOARD=local   
  displayName: 'Make Project'
```

When I run the build all 4 commands are just echoed on the terminal. How to execute them as separate commands in the same terminal session

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- script: |
    echo Building Software/linux_framework
    source /opt/pkg/linux/settings.sh
    cd Software/linux_framework
    make images HARDWARE=../my_xsa/ BOARD=local
  displayName: 'Make Project'
```

Pay attention to the difference between one-line script and multi-line script:

```
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Hello, world!
    echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```